# AWS S3 redirect containing static pages

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-services, redirect, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have 2 static website hosted on aws which has following setup.

1. 2 folders within a bucket B1, called A and B in S3.
2. Cloudfront is configured with bucket B1 as origin
3. Domain is configured as ABC.com
4. Websites are ABC.com/a/index.html and ABC.com/b/index.html

Note: 
a) We are not using S3 website hosting service. 
b) We can not use cloudfront error pages as web sites are different

Problem: If user types some random thing, instead of index.html like ABC.com/a/nahshhsjssj or ABC.com/b/hdggdggdgdg, it give 403 error. We want to serve respective index.html pages for 403 errors

I understand we can solve this issue by using Lambda @ Edge but I am looking for simple solution.

Comment: Is there a finite list of files that you want to serve? If so, can you set up the path patterns in your distribution in a way that serves all possible files under /a with the last being /a/* pointing to /a/index.html, and setup similar path patterns for /b?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in s3 static website hosting to redirect the request. You might need to look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html

Comment: We are not using S3 static website hosting.